# window focus event ctrlkey undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, undefined

I've an event :

```
$(window).on("focus", function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

My console log write when i focus google chrome and press ctrlKey :

```
jQuery.Event {
    altKey: undefined
    bubbles: false
    cancelable: false
    ctrlKey: undefined
    currentTarget: Window
    data: undefined
    delegateTarget: Window
    eventPhase: 2
    handleObj: Object
    isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse() {
    jQuery19108790766424499452: true
    metaKey: false
    originalEvent: Event
    relatedTarget: undefined
    shiftKey: undefined
    target: Window
    timeStamp: 1386764900891
    type: "focus"
    view: undefined
    which: undefined
}
```

Why CtrlKey is undefined when i press it and focus in the same time google's window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that workaround if it fits your needs:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6LUH/2/)

```
$(window).on("focus", windFocus);

function windFocus(){    
    $(this).one('keydown',checkCtrlKey).delay(100).queue(function(next){
        $(this).off('keydown',checkCtrlKey); next();
    });
    this.timeout = setTimeout(checkCtrlKey,100);
}

function checkCtrlKey(e){
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    if(!e || !e.ctrlKey) console.log("Ctrl NOT pressed!");
    else
     console.log("Ctrl IS pressed!");
}
```

Comment: Thank very much, it's perfect to detect if i've pressed ctrl key before focus on my window. Now I would like know if the ctrl key isn't pressed when i focus on google chrome windows

Comment: I've another question for your code why you need "delay" and "queue"?

Comment: this is used as a timeout to unbind keydown event, to avoid firing event later if no key was pressed when window got previously focused

Comment: How i can know now if the ctrl key isn't pressed when i focus?